# Fill up the angular form using casperjs and jquery

Tags: jquery, angular, casperjs

> I'm using casperjs to fill up the form, a simple form can be fill with casperjs and jquery but when i tried with casperjs and jquery to fill up the angular for it didn't work. Below is my example input field.

```
<input _ngcontent-c10="" autocomplete="off" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" type="password" ng-reflect-model="" ng-reflect-field-id="login_saveKey" ng-reflect-gd-field-map="[object Object]" id="login_saveKey" maxlength="8">
```

**Below are the solutions that i tried to solve the issue but didn't work**

```
-> $($('[ng-reflect-field-id="login_saveKey"]')[1]).val('23435621').trigger('input');
-> $('#login_saveKey').val('09876543').trigger('input');
-> $("form").find('input').eq(1).val("83749504").trigger("input");
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working, you can use

> this.sendKeys('input#login_saveKey', value);

thanks.